# Compactness in Infinite dimension

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, functional-analysis

I was looking for a characterization of the dimension of an nvs using Heine Borel theorem. suppose i have a Compact operator between an Hilbert space and itself, i want to proof that the autospace generated by the eigenvectors associated to one eigenvalues (i'll call it A_L) is finite dimensional. I know from the previous theorems and lemmas that A_L is closed, now my question is: if i show that the orthonormal base of A_L is bounded, precompact therefore compact, is it finite dimension?

Comment: Any collection of infinitely many mutually orthogonal elements of lengths bounded from below of an infinite dimensional innerproduct space is not totally bounded, and hence non compact.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $F$ be yur compact operator, $\lambda$ an eignevalue, $A_L$ the autospace. Then $F$ restricted to $A_L$ is just multiplication by $\lambda$.

But now $$\begin{matrix}
F:&A_L& \longrightarrow& A_L \\
 & x & \longmapsto & \lambda x
\end{matrix}$$
is a compact operator in the Hilbert space $A_L$, and this can happen if and only if $A_L$ is finite dimensional.